# Dates in T- SQL variable table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can someone help I can't get my dates to work. I can get it to read the Sysdatetime and add it to the table but I can't add dates Can someone give me a few tips on Dates etc.

```
Declare @mytable Table 
(ID int , Name char (10),Petowner char (10), Pettype char (10), CreateDate Date)

Insert into @mytable
Values (1,'Steve','Peter', 'Dog', ('18951024','yyyymmdd'),
       (2,'Sid',  'Marin', 'Fish',('18951024','yyyymmdd'),
       (3,'Stan', 'Nick',  'Cat', ('1895102','yyyymmdd')

Select ID as 'ID', Name as 'Pet name',Petowner as 'Owners name',
     Pettype as 'Pet type', CreateDate as 'Date'  
From @mytable
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking and I don't know where this weird format which involves more `(`s than `)`s sprang from (hint, in T-SQL, as with most programming languages, parentheses should be balanced)

Comment: you should troubleshoot the dates you're attempting to insert by just doing `SELECT ('1895102','yyyymmdd')` and verify it's the results you expect.  You'll find it produces an error.

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to add the date that's all and I can't work how to do it. Do you see How the rest is char or int I can't work out how to the date and the formatting within it. Thanks for many help sorry if I rushed the question a little

Comment: You can't add it because it's not a date and your query isn't attempting to convert it to a date.  What date value do you intend to have with a value like '18951024' ?  1895-10-24?  If that's the case, then use `CAST('18951024' AS DATE)` as the date value.

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert into @mytable
Values (1,'Steve','Peter', 'Dog', '18951024'),
   (2,'Sid',  'Marin', 'Fish', '18951024'),
   (3,'Stan', 'Nick',  'Cat', '18951102')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Insert into @mytable
Values (1,'Steve','Peter', 'Dog', '10/24/1895'),
       (2,'Sid',  'Marin', 'Fish','10/24/1895'),
       (3,'Stan', 'Nick',  'Cat', '10/2/1895')
```

Comment: I see so I just need to use a date format? That makes more sense. I think the website I looked at confused me. Can I convert it to an SQL format for example 102 or 103 etc? Using Convert just to make it more fancy

Comment: you could use CONVERT as part of the SELECT statement, like SELECT CONVERT(varchar,CreateDate,102) as [Date] ... or something like that.

Comment: I see now I think. Thank you